# ¿Por qué me da el error "fatal error" en este código?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int fila=4,colum=4;
int suma (int Matriz[][]);
int main()
{
    int Matriz[fila][colum]={{5,6,8,2},
                             {4,5,7,8},
                             {3,4,2,3},
                             {4,5,6,1}};

    return (Matriz);
}
int suma(int Matriz[][])
{

int suma=0;

for(int i=0;i<fila;i++)
    suma=suma+Matriz[][];
return suma;

}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es sumar todos los miembros de la matriz verdad?

Comment: Te ha servido la solución?

Answer (score 2):

He hecho algunas modificaciones y ahora funciona. Como te dije supongo que lo que quieres hacer es sumar todos los miembros de la matriz.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int fila = 4, colum = 4;
int suma(int matriz[fila][colum]);

int main() {
    int matriz[fila][colum] = {
        {5, 6, 8, 2},
        {4, 5, 7, 8},
        {3, 4, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6, 1}};

    //Estas dos lineas son solo para mostrar el resultado
    //podrias borrarlas y hacer: return suma(matriz);
    int result = suma(matriz);
    std::cout << result << endl;

    return result;
}

int suma(int matriz[fila][colum]) {

    int suma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fila; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < colum; j++){
            suma += matriz[i][j];
        }
    }            
    return suma;    
}
```

Aquí está el stacktrace:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TestProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c /home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:7:24: error: declaration of ‘Matriz’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
 int suma (int Matriz[][]);
                        ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:15:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)[4]’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     return (Matriz);
                   ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:10:9: warning: address of local variable ‘Matriz’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     int Matriz[fila][colum]={{5,6,8,2},
         ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp: At global scope:
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:17:23: error: declaration of ‘Matriz’ as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
 int suma(int Matriz[][])
                       ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp: In function ‘int suma(...)’:
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:23:15: error: ‘Matriz’ was not declared in this scope
     suma=suma+Matriz[][];
               ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:23:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     suma=suma+Matriz[][];
                      ^
/home/victor/Documentos/Programacion/C++/TestProject/TestProject/main.cpp:23:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     suma=suma+Matriz[][];
```